# "Qui c'est t'y": qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?

Tags: oral, argot

I'm assuming it means something like "well look who it is". Can anyone explain to me the grammatical function of "t'y" here?

Comment: Pas très beau, cette expression. Il vaux mieux ne pas l'utiliser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is simply "Who is it ?" (*Qui c'est ?* formally: *Qui est-ce ?*) and [*y* is here a short for *il*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/2) (he):

> *Qui c'est-t-il ?*

This is an outdated, colloquial way of asking nowadays only used for humorous effects but possibly also a regionalism.

Answer (score 0):

Qui est-ce?  Parisian slang (old )